# Unique Constraint Over Multiple Columns

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, seam, hibernate-mapping, seam2

I am using SEAM 2/Hibernate along with PostgreSQL 9 database. I have the following table

```
Active Band
===========
active_band_id serial
active_band_user text
active_band_date timestamp
active_band_process integer
```

I would like to add a constraint that ensures each new entry has a unique combination of active_band_user and active_band_date.

There could potentially be many attempted inserts per second so I need this to be as efficient as possible, is there a SEAM / hibernate annotation I can use in the entity mapping?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This appears to duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211972/specifying-restrictions-unique-together-in-hibernate

Answer (score 108, accepted):

There is no Hibernate annotation that checks uniqueness before insert/update. But there is annotation which will generate such a constraint to database if automatic database creation is used:

```
 @Table(
    name="ACTIVE_BAND", 
    uniqueConstraints=
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"active_band_user", "active_band_date"})
)
```

Comment: I dont think it supports this as I get 'The value for annotation attribute Table.uniqueConstraints must be some @javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint annotation' in Eclipse. Does this method generate the constraint in the SQL schema?

Comment: Yes it does support. It is documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Table.html#uniqueConstraints%28%29 Something else must be wrong. Is javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint imported?

Comment: I know this was years ago, but make sure you're using the `javax.persistence.Table` not `org.hibernate.annotations.Table`. Hibernate's `@Table` does not have a `uniqueConstraints` field.

Answer (score 2):

In a more modern syntax, it would be :

```
@Table(
    name="ACTIVE_BAND", 
    uniqueConstraints =
        [UniqueConstraint(
                columnNames = ["active_band_user", "active_band_date"]
        )]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This syntax worked for me with Java 17

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ELECTION_RESULTS",
    uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(name = "UC_CP", columnNames = { "constituency", "party_code" }) })
  
public class ElectionResults {
 @Column(..)
 ......
}
```