# How to add Unique Constraint on Entity class for Two different different combination of columns

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Want to add Unique Constraint for the combination of 2 diff diff columns

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/UniqueConstraint.html

Comment: Please refer the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955952/unique-constraint-over-multiple-columns

Comment: I need to know to configure the combination of 2 different column combinations and 2 different column combinations, Not only the combinations of columns but different different combinations of columns I want to know

Comment: The attribute is named `uniqueConstraints`, with a final `s`, indicating that you can pass several `UniqueConstraint`s.

Comment: @JBNizet  but in single combination, But I wanna do in two different combinations, like suppose you have a table with 6 columns(mbnumber,accno,nickname,id,name and remarks) and wanna to define unique on (mbnumber+accno) and (mbnumber+nickname)

Comment: Read my comment again. You can pass several UniqueConstraints: `uniqueConstraints={ @UniqueConstraint(...), @UniqueConstraint(...) }`.

Comment: @JBNizet   yup , thanks bro It happen. I am doing it in wrong way now its works thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no Hibernate annotation that checks uniqueness before insert/update. But there is annotation which will generate such a constraint to the database if automatic database creation is used:

Try this one: When hibernate create a table in DB create unique constraint combination of these two columns.

```
@Table(
    name="Table_Name", 
    uniqueConstraints=
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"Column1", "Column2"})
)
```