# How composite key in postgres affect hibernate performance? Shell I use artificial primary key instead?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, postgresql, indexing

In my application I use spring 3.2.4, hibernate 4.2.5, postgres 9.2.2. Tables are mapped through entity annotation and created through hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update in postgres.

The application often updates database, if there is no record, it is created then. Postgres creates automatic indexes on primary keys by default.

**1. Does Postgres handle searching by composite primary key with as same as speed as one-column primary key?**

**2. In this approach, isn't there performance degradation for hibernate compared to one-column keys?**

Thanks in advance

**Code:**

Composite Key:

```
@Embeddable
public class MyRecordKey implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -4966351432123537568L;
/**
 * In what interwal it was saved
 */
private String dateAndTime;

/**
 * name
 */
private String name;

      ...setters and getters ommited

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    ...code ommited
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            ...code ommtited
}



}
```

Table:

```
@Entity
public class MyRecord {

@EmbeddedId
private MyRecordKey myRecordKey;

    ...getters, setters and othey attributes ommited
}
```

Dao class:

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class SaveMyElements {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void saveElements(List<MyRecord> myRecordList) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        for (MyRecord chr : myRecordList) {
            session.saveOrUpdate(chr);
                    }

}
```

Datasource.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd        
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>


<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">

    <property name="driverClass" value="${app.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${app.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${app.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${app.password}" />

    <property name="minPoolSize" value="2" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="10" />
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="10" />

    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="200" />
    <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="10000" />
    <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="600" />
    <property name="automaticTestTable" value="conTest" />
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true" />
</bean>

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db.properties" />

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.my.myreader.hibernate.entity" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

ApplicationServlet-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd        
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">


<context:annotation-config />

<context:spring-configured />
<context:load-time-weaver />

<context:component-scan base-package="org.my.myreader"/>
<import resource="classpath:datasource.xml"/> 
    <import resource="classpath:spring-scheduler.xml"/>  
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, single-column, purely technical, auto-generated primary keys should be preferred. For performance reasons, but also for maintenance reasons:

1. Putting functional attributes in a PK prevents you from ever modifying their values
2. Every entity having a reference to MyRecord will have to also have these two columns.
3. Every link you make in yor webapp will need two parameters instead of just one to identify the address of the record in the application.
4. Everything, from your app to the database, will need more memory/disk space, and will be slower (an index on a numeric column is more efficient than an index on two separate columns, especially varchar ones)
5. You'll suffer when mapping and querying this entity and all the other ones referencing it.

...

Comment: Thanks for answer this tricky question @JB Nizet:) If i understand correctly, the best would be to create artificial key and mark my current primary key as unique "twins" as explained here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211972/specifying-restrictions-unique-together-in-hibernate